# MimeKit: How to embed images?

Tags: c#, mimekit

I am using MailKit/MimeKit 1.2.7 (latest NuGet version).

I tried to embed an image in the HTML body of my email by following the sample from the [API documentation](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/CreatingMessages.htm#CreateMessageWithAttachments) (section "Using a BodyBuilder").

My current code looks like this:

```
 var builder = new BodyBuilder();

 builder.HtmlBody = @"<p>Hey!</p><img src=""Image.png"">";

 var pathImage = Path.Combine(Misc.GetPathOfExecutingAssembly(), "Image.png");
 builder.LinkedResources.Add(pathLogoFile);
 message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
```

I can send this email and in fact the image **is** attached to the email. But it is **not** embedded.

Am I missing something? Or is this Apple Mail's fault (this is the email client I am using for receiving emails)?

I am grateful for any idea (and thanks so much to Jeffrey Stedfast for providing such a great toolset!!).

Ingmar

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try something a bit more like this:

```
var builder = new BodyBuilder ();
var pathImage = Path.Combine (Misc.GetPathOfExecutingAssembly (), "Image.png");
var image = builder.LinkedResources.Add (pathLogoFile);

image.ContentId = MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId ();

builder.HtmlBody = string.Format (@"<p>Hey!</p><img src=""cid:{0}"">", image.ContentId);

message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody ();
```

If this works for you, I'll update the documentation.

The problem might be that Apple's `multipart/related` implementation does not resolve the `Image.png` reference using the `Content-Location` header on the image mime part (possibly because it is a relative URL).

The `cid:` URL-type should work, though, but it's a bit more awkward to construct since you need to know the `Content-Id` values for each image attachment.

Comment: Good morning. And thanks for your tip. Works great! In fact I have been using the cid: stuff with my old email component as well (before switching to MailKit). So, this solution is perfect for me. THX again.

Comment: I ran into a couple more issues though today. I will put them in separate questions/posts here on stackoverflow and would be more than happy if you had a couple more easy solutions for me :)

Comment: I'm having problems with embedded images. I use basically the same approach. BodyBuilder.LinkedResources.Add()  The attachment arrives. But its marked as a regular attachment and not 'inline'. In my own client I see the ContentDiposition and looks like a regular attachment. Outlook, still renders the image but also shows an attachment icon in the email list as if the email had regular attachments. Any idea?

Comment: Fixed: https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/commit/7134e0542f39ccb290cb34db89290937f1916762

Comment: I explicitly set IsAttachment = false on the MimeEntity that is returned by BodyBuilder.LinkedResources.Add()  before sending. Is your fix doing anything else. If not I would still expect the same behavior.

Comment: Can you paste the raw message in your question? Without it, all I can do is guess at the problem.

Comment: Actually, n/m, this is your problem: `builder.HtmlBody = @"<p>Hey!</p><img src=""Image.png"">";` While it is legal to refer to images by name, some clients do not handle it well. Instead, I would recommend referring to them by their `Content-Id` header value using the following syntax: `<img src=""cid:{content-id-without-brackets}"">`

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the cid:identifier must be URL encoded as per RFC2392, even though this behaviour is only properly documented in the errata of that RFC (!). This caused me a quite a bit of pain producing compliant emails, until I found this out.

Comment: Hello, I have also problem of embedding images in html template, I have one html template, and I am using this template to send email body part, I have used your above code and added LinkedResources and set in my html template as like this : <img width=191 height=42
src="cid:companylogo" > and in the code side, i have write as like this :  

var image = builder.LinkedResources.Add(logoPath);

 image.ContentId = "companylogo";

    But still, I am not getting embedded images in my email

Comment: Any examples for in-memory images with no path?

Comment: Yes, use any of the AttachmentCollection.Add() methods that take a Stream or byte[]. The `fileName` parameter in those methods is just used for naming the attachment, it is not opened or read at all.

Answer (score 5):

Just for reference, this can be found under http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Creating-Messages.htm now. The link in the original answer is broken.