# How to convert image data url into contentid in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

In application I used Tinymce editor in which if images inserted then it is stored like below :-

```
<div>
<img src="D:\My Folder\pic1.jpg" />
<img src="D:\My Folder\pic2.png" />
<img src="D:\My Folder\pic3.gif" />
</div>
```

I want to replace image url path with content id.

```
<div>
    <img src="cid:{0}" />
    <img src="cid:{1}" />
    <img src="cid:{2}" />
</div>
```

is it possible?

Comment: Content ID may mean YouTube's content ID, or the `cid:` scheme used in emails or .... ? What contentiid are you talking about? If it's about email, you should be asking how to embed images in your emails? Or what library to use for this?

Comment: i want cid: for emails.

Comment: @RookiCoder then you should be looking for email libraries and how to embed images. This has nothing to do with ASP.NET and little to do with URLs. There are many relevant SO questions, eg [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212838/c-sharp-sending-mails-with-images-inline-using-smtpclient).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i want to know how can we replace src urls with cid. taking html bdy content from tinymce and trying to convert into cid using linksource and replace same url with cid

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can u give me some reference link?

Comment: Replacing URLs has *nothing* to do with creating emails and embeding attachments. It's like asking what color of fob to choose when you don't have a car yet. Google for `SmtpClient embed image` or `MailKit embed image`. The built-in SmptClient is considered obsolete. [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) is one of the most popular replacements

Comment: SO question about embedding images with MailKit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406784/mimekit-how-to-embed-images)